# how to invoke a method in string in Javascript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to invoke a method in string in Javascript or JQuery ? for example, how to invoke the 'func' ?

Thanks

```
function invoke(condition, func){
    if(condition){
        // how to invoke func
    }
}
 -------
invoke((1==1), function(){
            alert('run');
     });
```

Comment: Did you try `func()`?

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a function reference as a parameter to `invoke`(it is not a string), so you can invoke the passed function like

```
function invoke(condition, func) {
    if (condition) {
        func()
    }
}

invoke((1 == 1), function () {
    alert('run');
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GEj4z/9/)**